# print different types of console messages(console.debug, console.info, etc) with type stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Looking to use a variable for a method of console interface.

Instead of using a large if condition

```
if (method == 'debug')
 console.debug(val)

if (method == 'error')
 console.error(val)

if (method == 'info')
 console.info(val)
```

I do below in Javascript, works fine:

```
const method='debug';
const val = 'to be printed';
console[method](val);
```

How can I do same in Typescript? Exact same line from javascript returns below error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Console'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Console'
```

Comment: Unless you're using `let` instead of `const`, `method` should be typed as the literal `"debug"`, not as a `string`. This code should work fine: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.2.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYwLwwORRDARgUxgAcAnASzCnwBMMBuAKAdElgFt8oALEatTavlwBXAOb1m4CCCT4A2h268AugApESAJSMGs9px7UATPwBEgkaNOMW02QoO8jajdqa3YFDWWoBZR3zopgAi+ABCwgDi1pKQMvJeyD7+StQuyNpAA)

Comment: `let method: 'debug' | 'error' | 'info'`

Comment: I wonder why these are comments and not answers?